# How do I fix the problem when I try to use seeder in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-seeding

I am trying to add a super user in my laravel project. I have but the error occors.

```
The use statement with non-compound name 'SuperAdminSeeder' has no effect", "E:\github\LARAVEL\Deal-Ocean\database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php", ["E:\github\LARAVEL\Deal-Ocean\vendor\composer/../../database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php"]
```

**SuperAdminSeeder.php**

```php
<?php

use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class SuperAdminSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'super_admin']);
        $user = User::create(['email' => 'imrulhasan273@email.com', 'imrulhasan' => bcrypt('secret')]);
        DB::table('role_user')->insert(['user_id' => $user->id, 'role_id' => $role->id]);
    }
}
```

On the above query I am creating a super user with id name and role. And also create their role_id and user_id in pivot table.

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```php
<?php

use SuperAdminSeeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SuperAdminSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `use SuperAdminSeeder;` line, run a `composer dumpautoload` just to make sure and then try again ;)

Comment: I guess, `Migrations ` and `Seeders` do not use `PSR-4` autoloading. They `require` the files from the respective folders instead. So you can remove the `use SuperAdminSeeder` statement from the top.

Comment: Thanks. This problem is solved may be..But another exception comes "      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")"  This is my roles table ``` Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });```

Comment: `'imrulhasan' => bcrypt('secret')` Should that be `'password' => bcrypt('secret')`? Do you have a column named `imrulhasan` in your table? Also, you need to add a `name` for your user

Comment: Thanks everyone... Problem solved.... I am grateful to all of you

Comment: Sorry bro... I have mistakenly put name instead of column name... Thanks for your help.. Problem solved now. I I had problems here. THe column name and the `use SuperAdminSeeder`. Now everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DatabaseSeeder` is not in a dedicated namespace; it is in the global namespace. Because of this, you don't need to `use` any other classes that are also in the global namespace.

Since `SuperAdminSeeder` is also in the global namespace, the `use SuperAdminSeeder;` statement in your `DatabaseSeeder` does not do anything (except cause the error).

Remove the `use SuperAdminSeeder;` statement.